# Unit test GetHashCode with developer time in mind

Tags: .net, unit-testing, iequalitycomparer

In my current project I have several IEqualitycomparers.
These take several properties of an object and compare them.
Properties can be either equal, different and this both for values and null.

I want to unit test these, but all the different possibilities are insane.
How can I efficiently test these?

**Update**
Currently they get their values through properties and not constructors as they are filled with entlib's data block.

example (in vb.net, but I talk C# too):

```
Public Class GuarantyEqualityComparer
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Guaranty)

    Public Overloads Function Equals(x As Guaranty, y As Guaranty) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Guaranty).Equals
        Return x.ClientCode = y.ClientCode AndAlso x.LocationCode = y.LocationCode AndAlso x.CategoryCode = y.CategoryCode AndAlso x.GuarantyCode = y.GuarantyCode
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function GetHashCode(obj As Guaranty) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Guaranty).GetHashCode
        Const format As String = "{0}{1}{2}{3}"
        Return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, obj.ClientCode, obj.LocationCode, obj.CategoryCode, obj.GuarantyCode).GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: As an aside, that's really not a great way of generating a hash code. +1 for a useful question though :)

Comment: Can you tell us more about how the types you're comparing will be constructed? For example, will there always be a constructor with all the relevant parts?

Comment: Currently there is no constructor requiring these values. They can be null. About your aside: true I remember now there's an answer or article from you about good hashcodes. To be honest, all the equality and hashcode systems have always eluded me.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I guess you're asking about the ctor thing because you want to know if the fields are going to be immutable. Functionally they will be, but there's no technical reason they are.

Comment: Not really - I'm mostly asking in order to know how a helper class could construct instances. I don't mind what *other* constructors there are, so long as there's one which allows the construction based on all values.

Comment: Adding a constructor with those parameters is a valid option. PS: have been looking into hash algorithms a bit and they all use unchecked parts. In VB.net this doesn't exist on this granularity. Furthermore I have to take Null into account.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, given the possibility of having a constructor, I would try to write a utility class which allows you to specify sample values for each constructor parameter:

```
var comparer = new GuarantyEqualityComparer();
var tester = EqualityTester<Guaranty>.CreateBuilder(comparer)
                 .AddValue("ClientCode", "Sample1", "Sample2", null)
                 .AddValue("LocationCode", 1, 3, 0)
                 .Builder();
tester.Test();
```

The tester would go through each possible permutation, and at *least* check:

- `x.Equals(y)` when `x` and `y` were built with the same values
- `x.GetHashCode() == y.GetHashCode()` when `x` and `y` were built with the same values
- `!x.Equals(y)` when `x` and `y` were built with different values

It *could* also check that `x.GetHashCode() != y.GetHashCode()` when `x` and `y` were built with different values. This is *not* required by the contract of `GetHashCode`, and even a good hash code will always have cases where that would fail (for any type with more than 2<sup>32</sup> possible values) but it would still be a reasonable sanity check - you'd normally have to be very unlucky to pick sample values which failed when the code was correct.

---

In terms of hash code generation, I always use something along the lines of:

```
int hash = 19;
hash = hash * 31 + HashOfField1;
hash = hash * 31 + HashOfField2;
...
return hash;
```

For Noda Time, we've got some of this in a [helper class](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime/Utility/HashCodeHelper.cs) which allows for methods like this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = HashCodeHelper.Initialize();
    hash = HashCodeHelper.Hash(hash, LocalInstant);
    hash = HashCodeHelper.Hash(hash, Offset);
    hash = HashCodeHelper.Hash(hash, Zone);
    return hash;
}
```

The helper handles nullity for you. All of this is *much* nicer than creating a string via formatting every time you need to compute a hash code.